# what's "sure kill" when talking about NFS mount option?

Tags: kill, nfs

In the following link

http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/NFS-HOWTO.html

It said a process is not killable except by a "sure kill", but what's sure kill?

> hard (NFS client mount option)
>
> The program accessing a file on a NFS
>   mounted file system will hang when the
>   server  crashes. The process cannot be
>   interrupted or killed (**except by a
>   "sure kill"**) unless you  also
>   specify intr. When the NFS server is
>   back online the program will continue
>   undisturbed  from where it was. We
>   recommend using hard,intr on all NFS
>   mounted file systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means `kill -9`, though please note that you are reading a quite old howto (as most other TLDP howtos, I think) from 2002 year, and regarding NFS mount options `hard,intr` are already default and

> The intr / nointr mount option is
>   deprecated after kernel 2.6.25.  Only
>   SIGKILL can interrupt a pending  NFS 
>   operation on these kernels, and if
>   specified, this mount option is
>   ignored to provide backwards
>   compatibility with older kernels.